# How to dismiss the Popover View in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uipopovercontroller

I have 4 buttons in my app.If i click on first button Popover view will come.when i press on the screen that Popover view will disappear.(This is first method.It is working fine)

**Second Method**
If i click on first button popover view will come and next if i click on the 2nd button that Popover View should automatically has to disappear and the second button Popover View has to come.

But for me it is not coming like that.If i click on the 2nd button it disappearing the 1st button Popover View and not displaying the 2nd button Popover View.

I am new to Objective-c ,Can anyone please help to solve this problem?

Thanks in Adavnce

Comment: i think but not sure which view or controller will be on top.that view will get contact first you are clicking outside second pop up view then it will consider as outside of second popup not on 1st button.

Comment: which popover you are using? Use [KGModal](https://github.com/kgn/KGModal). To dimiss KGModal there is method as [self dismiss];

Comment: Yes that popup is on top of the viewcontroller.How to solve it?

Comment: @iworld : are you using KGModal?

Comment: @iworld : if u r using KGModal, use `[[KGModal sharedInstance] hideAnimated:YES];` to dismiss...

Comment: @iworld : does your problem solved?

Comment: No iam using UIPopOverController

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don`t understand you problem very well, but i hope this helps, on the method that call the pop over.

```
- (void)callMyPopOver 
{
    if (self.firstPopOver != nil) 
    {
        [self.firstPopOver dismissPopoverAnimated:NO];
    }
    //call your second pop over..
}
```